# Groupby multiple including children and then sum

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core

Using the tables below I would like to sum the dose for each site that is the same course, I want to first group by course and then site and then sum the dose.

Radiation

| RadiationId | CourseId | Dose |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 |

RadiationSites

| RadiationId | SiteId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |

Output

| CourseId | SiteId | Total Dose | CourseName | Site |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | Course 1 | Spleen |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | Course 1 | Spine |
| 1 | 3 | 30 | Course 1 | Eye |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | Course 2 | Spleen |

I tried something like the following but can't get my head around it.

```
    var totals =
    dbContext
        .Radiations
        .Include(r => r.RadiationSites)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.Site)
        .Include(r => r.RadiationCourse)
        .Where(r => r.Nhi == NHI)
        .SelectMany(s => s.RadiationSites, (Radiation, RadiationSites) => new { Radiation, RadiationSites } )
        .GroupBy(r => r.Radiation.RadiationCourseId, r => r.RadiationSites.SiteId);
```

Is it even possible? Please help!

Comment: As you might be able to tell from the answers you got, doing Joins using the query comprehension syntax is often easier than using the functional syntax. Each syntax has its advantages. Don't worry that one has an execution time advantage

Comment: It would help to have the code of the classes in the question. Also, when asking questions about EF it's important to know the exact version, because versions differ in query shapes they support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing I don't like about the other answers is that either:

- They use local objects, which can behave differently to EF queries; not every query you can write in a local LINQ style is translatable to SQL by EF and/or
- They don't leverage the fact that EF knows how to join tables because it knows the relationships between them; all you have to do is navigate along the join properties EF provides and EF does the joining.

  - Writing joins yourself when you have EF is like buying a car and pushing it to the shops instead of starting the engine.. Sure if the engine breaks down you might have to push it, but mostly you'd seek to drive it

Anyway, there are some important teaching points here. One of them is your task can be vastly easier depending on where you start. Let's do this with EF and see how it looks.

I replicated your DB as much as I could understand it from your post:

[image]

[image]

It doesn't matter if this doesn't match exactly, but it's helpful to have a diagram when writing code, to aid with naviagtion. Don't worry about minor differences, like maybe you don't have a RadiationSiteId..

Main point: your life would be considerably easier if you start from RadiationSites; it's the Many end of two relationships and only has parents. Being "in" a child object and navigating up to a parent is typically a lot easier than being in a parent and picking one of its many children

You don't need to Include; Include is not JOIN. There are more voluminous tomes you can read on this, but Include is for when you're downloading whole objects and you want to tell EF what other whole, related objects to bring in too. Grouping queries probably don't result in an output object that is wholly an object from the schema, but instead use some other projection to e.g. an anonymous type, so skip the Include. You don't need Include for EF to be able to "see" related data youre accessing - when you use the navigation properties in the Where, GroupBy and Select etc EF will see you travelling from one object to another and form the necessary joins for you in the background

```
        var totals = await db.RadiationSites
            .Where(rs => rs.Radiation.Nhi == nhi)
            .GroupBy(rs => new { rs.Radiation.CourseId, rs.SiteId, rs.Radiation.Course.CourseName, rs.Site.SiteName })
            .Select(g => new { g.Key.CourseId, g.Key.SiteId, TotalDose = g.Sum(rs => rs.Radiation.Dose), g.Key.CourseName, g.Key.SiteName })
            .ToArrayAsync();
```

We start from RadiationSites, and Where up into Radiation to insist that NHI is some value. EF will see this and make the join, however it feels like doing so.

Because we're low down in the relationship hierarchy (thinking of it like a family tree where children are below parents), grouping is similarly easy; we only go as far up the tree as we need to. In some databases you could get away with just grouping by the primary key and the DB knows that implicitly all other columns from that table must be unique, but SQLS likes to have all columns grouped even if e.g. for a course ID of 1 there is never going to be any other value for the course name. Because we want the course name, we fetch it into the grouping key because it'll make life simpler later. We can reach `CourseId` by only going up to `Radiation.CourseId`, but we'll have to navigate further to get the name - `Radiation.Course.CourseName`

Ultimately, the way to have this not break your head is to look at your desired output; you want CourseId, SiteId, CourseName, and SiteName as the non grouped (the key) columns, and you want the Sum of the dose as an aggregated column. Put all those key columns into the object you group on: `new { rs.Radiation.CourseId, rs.SiteId, rs.Radiation.Course.CourseName, rs.Site.SiteName }`. If you want to simplify things some you could always group on just the IDs, i.e. `{ rs.Radiation.CourseId, rs.SiteId }`, and fetch the related data later, maybe even by separate query

Then there is the Select, where you pull the key values out again (bit repetitive) but help yourself out by naming the input variable to the Select `g` or similar, to reflect the fact that it's a group (a collection of collection-of-RadiationSites), with a `.Key` that specifies what all the sites therein were grouped under, and itself is a collection of RadationSites. This is why I use `g` inside the `Select`, but `rs` inside the `Sum`, because the Sum is skipping over a "group" of RadiationSites and adding up the `Dose`

And there you have it:

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer and fantastic teachings to go with it. I will think about the starting point moving forward and great tip about includes. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Sites table with SiteId and SiteName columns and a Courses table with CourseId and CourseName columns, your  query would look something like this:

```
var totals = from rad in dbContext.Radiations
             join radSite in dbContext.RadiationSites on rad.RadiationId equals radSite.RadiationId
             join site in dbContext.Sites on radSite.SiteId equals site.SiteId
             join course in dbContext.Courses on rad.CourseId equals course.CourseId
             group new { rad, site.SiteName, course.CourseName } by new { rad.CourseId, radSite.SiteId } into grouped
             select new {
                 CourseId = grouped.Key.CourseId,
                 SiteId = grouped.Key.SiteId,
                 TotalDose = grouped.Sum(x => x.rad.Dose),
                 CourseName = grouped.Select(x => x.CourseName).FirstOrDefault(),
                 SiteName = grouped.Select(x => x.SiteName).FirstOrDefault()
             };

var result = totals.ToList();
```

Here

- The from ... join ... syntax is used to join the tables based on
  their relationships.
- The group ... by ... into grouped syntax is used to group the results
  by both CourseId and SiteId.
- The select new syntax is used to project the final result, where we
  sum the doses for each group and also select the CourseName and
  SiteName based on the first occurrence in each group (assuming that
  names are consistent within groups).
- Replace dbContext.Sites and dbContext.Courses with the actual DBSet
  properties from your DbContext if those are the names of your
  entities that contain the site and course details.

Comment: Do not use joins explicitly if there are navigation properties. For example `join radSite...` can be replaced by `from radSite in rad.RadiationSites` and other joins also.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your data as valid C# code:

```
var sites = new[]
{
    new { SiteId = 1, Site = "Spleen", },
    new { SiteId = 2, Site = "Spine", },
    new { SiteId = 3, Site = "Eye", },
};

var courses = new[]
{
    new { CourseId = 1, Course = "Course 1", },
    new { CourseId = 2, Course = "Course 2", },
};

var radiations = new[]
{
    new { RadiationId = 1, CourseId = 1, Dose = 10, },
    new { RadiationId = 2, CourseId = 1, Dose = 20, },
    new { RadiationId = 3, CourseId = 2, Dose = 5, },
};

var radiationSites = new[]
{
    new { RadiationId = 1, SiteId = 1, },
    new { RadiationId = 1, SiteId = 2, },
    new { RadiationId = 1, SiteId = 3, },
    new { RadiationId = 2, SiteId = 3, },
    new { RadiationId = 3, SiteId = 1, },
};
```

Now your query looks like this:

```
var query =
    from course in courses
    join radiation in radiations on course.CourseId equals radiation.CourseId
    join radiationSite in radiationSites on radiation.RadiationId equals radiationSite.RadiationId
    join site in sites on radiationSite.SiteId equals site.SiteId
    group radiation.Dose by new
    {
        course.CourseId,
        site.SiteId,
        course.Course,
        site.Site,
    } into gs
    select new
    {
        gs.Key.CourseId,
        gs.Key.SiteId,
        TotalDose = gs.Sum(),
        gs.Key.Course,
        gs.Key.Site,
    };
```

That produces:

[image: query]